# Наложение логотипа и стримминг в связке FFmpeg+FFServer

Tags: ffmpeg

Стоит задача RTSP стримминга (FFmpeg в роли сервера не подходит - очень не стабилен при запуске) с наложением логотипа (watermark). Существует много решений для организации наложения watermark на поток от входного устройства, с последующей записью в файл. К сожалению, применяемый overlay в составе filter_complex, почему-то не работает при передаче потока FFserver-у. 
Использую FFServer со след. конфигурацией (в среде windows):

```
============================================================================
    HTTPPort 8090
    RTSPPort 554
    HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
    MaxClients 100
    MaxBandwidth 20000
    <Feed feed1.ffm>
    File c:/tmp/feed1.ffm
    FileMaxSize 100M
    Launch ffmpeg -f dshow -i "video=HP Webcam" -i watermark.png -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -filter_complex overlay -an -s 800x600 -r 10 -vcodec h264 -y test.avi -f ffm -vcodec copy
    </Feed>
    <Stream live>
    NoDefaults
    Feed feed1.ffm
    Format rtp
    VideoSize vga
    VideoFrameRate 6
    VideoBitRate 200
    VideoCodec mpeg4
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
    PreRoll 0
    NoAudio
    </Stream> 
    =============================================================================
```

Отдельно строка запуска FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i "video=HP Webcam" -i watermark.png -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -filter_complex overlay -an -s 800x600 -r 10 -vcodec h264 -y test.avi -f ffm -vcodec copy
```

Запуск  FFmpeg специально делаю с 2 выводами: первый в test.avi, второй (по умолчанию) на HTTP порт сервера (http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm). В выходном потоке сервера (rtsp://localhost:554/live) на просмотре видео watermark отсутствует, а в файле test.avi он есть!

Помогите понять, в чем причина? Буду признателен за любую помощь в этом вопросе!

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте подробнее официальную документацию, а не опусы в интернетах. Как минимум нарисуйте схематический граф фильтров. Начнём с того, что выходы фильтров подключаются в соотношении 1:1, а так же то, что для работы фильтров необходимо раскодировать видео и потом его кодировать (есть т.н. bitstream фильтры, которые имеют дело с запакованными данными, но это из другой оперы).

Так вот, вы не указывали как подключается фильтр. `overlay` имеет два входа: поток и оверлей и один выход. На входе два потока, первый видео, он автоматом подключился на вход оверлея, второй картинка - он автоматом подключился как источник оверлея. А вот на выходе два назначения. Собственно по-умолчанию подключился первый, тот, который в файл пишется.

А второй выход... По идее FFmpeg не сильно умничает и может на выходе автоматически поставить `split` фильтр (или `tee`, по памяти пишу). Но вы явно указали `-codec copy`, что запрещает раскодировку и поэтому данные для этого выхода снимаются до всей цепочки фильтров. Поэтому там ничего нет.

Перекодируйте тоже, задайте кодек, как для avi, параметры кодирования и т.п.